# Writing data to file in C [Serialization]

Tags: c, database, struct

I have a struct that I want to save in a data file.

```
typedef struct Photo {
    char name[20];
    char description[100];
} photo;
```

I'd like to be able to save many of these structs in a file, much like a database. The only way I can see in doing that would be through `fwrite()` which has problems when it comes to platform mobility, and to just write `photo->name, photo->description` as ascii. I would really like to avoid having to parse all of the raw text data. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really understand what you are asking but you can also write to files using `fprintf`.

And if you are asking how to store the data in the file for faster lookup, use hash tables, at the start of the file have a table which points to memory locations for the structure along with a hash value(of the name parameter).

When querying the file all you have to do is match the hash value and then jump to that specific location.